# jQuery making a global variable

Tags: jquery

So, I have a following js var:

```
var rhpp_id = jQuery(this).parents('.rhp').data("pi");
```

This is inside of function. However I am using the same line in multiple functions and I was wondering if there is a way of making this exact line as a global variable that I can use in other functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it outside all your functions? variables are global when not restricted in scope in javascript. `jquery(this)` should refer to the page context when not referring to a web control or tag

Comment: the issue is `jquery(this)`. I seem to have an issue with this particular portion

Comment: no worries. =) thanks thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a var outside of your functions and set it's value inside the function where $(this) is valid:

```
var rhpp_id = "";

$('#divname').click(function () {
    rhpp_id = jQuery(this).parents('.rhp').data("pi");
});
```

Then you can access it globally.

Comment: Ah, i see. That's perfect. Thank you so much! =) It worked.